# Why does Brent/Salamin algorithm double the digits of $\pi$ with each iteration?

Tags: convergence-divergence, pi

The [Brent-Salamin-Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Brent-SalaminFormula.html) uses the arithmetic-geometric mean to calculate $\pi$.

There are many sophisticated proofs proving very sharp error bounds, for example in [Salamin's 1976 paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2005327) or in [this 2018 paper by Richard Brent, equation (20), p. 9](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07558).

**Is there an easy way to prove the (much weaker) error bound $|\pi-p_{n+1}|<|\pi-p_n|^2$?**

A partial solution proving the quadratic convergence of the AGM is this:

\begin{align*}
    d_{n+1}&=c_{n+1}^2 =a_{n+1}^2-b_{n+1}^2\\
    &= \left(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\right)^2-a_n\cdot b_n\\
    &= \frac{a_n^2+2a_nb_n+b_n^2-4a_nb_n}{4}\\
    &= \left(\frac{a_n-b_n}{2}\right)^2\\
    &=\frac{(a_n-b_n)^2\cdot(a_n+b_n)^2}{4\cdot(a_n+b_n)^2}\\
    &= \frac{(a_n^2-b_n^2)^2}{4\cdot(a_n+b_n)^2}\\
    &< \frac{\left(c_n^2\right)^2}{4\cdot\left(1/\sqrt{2}+1/\sqrt{2}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\cdot d_n^2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy proof of the quadratic convergence can be found on p. 13-14 of [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.04110.pdf).